# IEnumerable array disappeared in Visual C#

Tags: asp.net, linq, datatable, ienumerable, datarow

I declared a IEnumerable array

```
IEnumerable<DataRow>[] drs=new IEnumerable<DataRow>[5];
```

and populated it by

```
for(int i=0;i<5;i++)
{
    drs[i]=
        from x in dt.AsEnumerable()                 //dt is a DataTable
        where x["ID"].ToString() == i.ToString()    //Assuming dt has a column named ID
        select x;
}
```

When I get out of the scope of the for loop, the data I populated are all gone. Why is this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Linq expressions are lazy evaluated. That means that C# doesn't actually access the record set in the code above. Rather, it just keeps track of an expression that will access the data some later time.

In the case of collection of DataRows this can cause problem because 'later' might mean after the database connection (or at least the resultset) is closed.

Fix this by forcing Linq to evaluate the enumerables at the time, for example by calling ToList().

```
for(int i=0;i<5;i++)
{
    drs[i]=
        (from x in dt.AsEnumerable()                 //dt is a DataTable
        where x["ID"].ToString() == i.ToString()    //Assuming dt has a column named ID
        select x).ToList();
}
```